# Is it possible to extend a layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout

In my application I need to use the `RecyclerView` in two different activities.
I was thinking to extend the layout, because the base layout (the recycler view) is the same for the two activities, but I don't know if it's possible.
With "to extend a layout" I mean something like this:

If this is my `base_layout.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to do something like this in my `child_layout.xml`:

```
include "base_layout.xml" 
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAddVehicle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+"
            android:onClick="launchAddVehicleActivity"/>
```

so, the activity which uses `chid_layout.xml` will have got a `RecyclerView` and a `Button` inside.

Is it possible to do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a generic layout, then add it on your layout's activities.

Generic Layout
my_generic_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/generic_layout">
  <RecyclerView/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout's Activities

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/layout_1">
<include layout="@layout/my_generic_layout" />
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/layout_2">
<include layout="@layout/my_generic_layout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this `<include layout="@layouts/chid_layout" />`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the button inside the layout you need to write a Custom Component. See Android Documentation here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

Basically you could create a class which inherits from RelativeLayout which inflates base_layout.xml

Comment: thank you, but I think that a simply `include` tag as suggested by jmarkstar and ZeroOne will be fine